# twilio AxiosError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.twilio.com error

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have this request OTP function:

```
export const onRequestOTP = async (otp: number, toPhoneNumber: string) => {
    const accountSid = "ACe5f8edddd5ad84xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Placeholder for your Account SID
    const authToken = "58ccc5e08d9axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Placeholder for your Auth Token
    const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

    const response = await client.messages.create({
        body: `Your OTP is ${otp}`,
        from: "+19285xxxxxxx", // Placeholder for your Twilio phone number
        to: `+234${toPhoneNumber}`,
    });

    return response;
};
```

But I get an error while testing the `OTP` request of:

```
AxiosError.call(axiosError, error.message, code, config, request, response);
             ^
AxiosError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.twilio.com and a bunch of hostname, syscall, code, and cause sections
```

.

I was expecting an `OTP`  to be sent to the to: number and a token as the response.

Comment: I think it can be some network restriction on your country. can you ping any other Twilio urls?